# Using a stack in c++

Tags: c++, stl, stack

For a class I have to use a stack. From what I can tell I create a stack with

```
#include <stack>
class c1
{
    stack<Point> openstack;
};
```

Point is a class I created that has an x and y int value to store points for using in simple 2D graphics. The problem I'm having is that if I do

```
Point p = openstack.pop();
```

I get an error: "No suitable consturtor exists to convert from void to Point"

Point has a set function that takes a point and will use the passed point to store the x and y values but this does not work either.

```
Point p;
p.set(openstack.pop()); // does not work
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? If you need info please ask - I can give more if needed.

Comment: You could answer your own question if you read some documentation. If you don't have a good book, [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) is another good source.

Comment: [Reading the manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop) would have avoided this question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pop()` doesn't return a value. It just removes the top value. It's declared like this:

```
void pop();
```

To get the top value you need to call `top()`. After that you can call `pop()`.

```
Point p = openstack.top();
openstack.pop();
```

There are [a couple reasons](http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2005/10/why-does-stdstackpop-returns-void.html) why `pop()` does not return the value popped.